# How do I fix NoClassDefFoundError in Android for android.widget.PopupMenu?

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, popupmenu

I am trying to create a popup menu and I keep getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.widget.PopupMenu

```
    public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tweet_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

I realize this error means that the class is found in the classpath at compile, but not at runtime, but I am having trouble figuring out why, as this is part of Android SDK.  I am using the newest version of the SDK and I am developing/compiling in Netbeans.

Please help!

Comment: if any error occurs always put full logcat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PopupMenu is available since `Android API 11`. So in order to use you need a device with at least `Android 3.0`. Please refer to the [Android developers docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

Comment: thanks, that's def the issue.  Guess I need to find a new solution.